# Propriedade startDate não funciona em datepicker

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando fazer um calendário onde terá algumas regras, são elas:

- Não pode ser final de semana
- Data inicial +45 dias
- Bloquear feriados

Porém o `startDate` não funciona. Código abaixo:

```
$(function() {
    var diasSemana = [ "Domingo", "Segunda", "Terca", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sabado" ];
    var diasFinalSemana = [ "Domingo", "Sabado" ];
    
    var datasIndisponiveis = [
        new Date(2022, 04, 20),
        new Date(2022, 05, 27),
        new Date(2022, 05, 05)
    ].map(function (data) {
        return data.getTime();
    });
    
    $('[date-datepicker]').datepicker({
        startDate: '+45d',
        beforeShowDay: function(data){    
      
            var diaSemana = diasSemana[data.getDay()];
            var isDataIndisponivel = datasIndisponiveis.indexOf(data.getTime()) != -1;
            var isDataFinalSemana = diasFinalSemana.indexOf(diaSemana) != -1;
            return [!isDataIndisponivel && !isDataFinalSemana];
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

O parâmetro startDate apenas define a data que aparece no calendário. Para atualizar o input tens que usar o método "setDate".

```
$("[date-datepicker]").datepicker("setDate", "+45d");
```